# I'm trying to take inputs from an HTML form and pass it to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, html-formhandler

I created an if statement to test if either field is blank and to make sure the values of the form are making it to the function. I've tried a few variations to the HTML and JavaScript on either ends of the process but still nothing happens. I've posted my current HTML document and JavaScript code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Also not all of the `document.getElementById('').innerHTML = ;` and  `<td>`  tags are set up yet.

HTML

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<!-- LINKS TO STYLES AND JAVASCRIPT -->

<!-- <script src="weatherPull.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> -->

<script src="getWeatherData.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="page3.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Girassol&family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- START OF PAGE AND PAGE TITLE -->

<html>

<header>
<title> Weather </title>
</header>
<body>

<!------ TITLE AND NAV BAR ------>

<div id="titleBar">

<h1 id="title"> The Title </h1>

</div>
<div id="navBar">

<nav>
<a href="index.html" > Home </a>

<a href="page1.html" > Page 1 </a>

<a href="/phpmyadmin" > phpMyAdmin </a>

<a href="about.html" > About </a>

<a href="template.html" > Page 3 </a>
</nav>

</div>

<!---- LOCATION SELECTION FORM ---->

<div id="weatherForm">

<h1> Weather Data Pull</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" name="weatherForm">
 
<label id="zipCode" for="zipCode"> Enter Zip Code: </label>
<input type="text" name="zipCode" placeholder="Required" id="zipCodeEnter"><br>

<label for="country" id="country"> Select Country: </label>
<select name="country" form="country" id="countrySelect" >
  <option value="us">US</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
</select><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getWeather()">

</form>

</div>

<!------- WEATHER RESULTS -------->

<div id="weatherResults">

<h1 id="location"></h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="longitude">stuff</td>
        <td id="latitude">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="weather">stuff</td>
        <td id="windSpeed">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="windGust">stuff</td>
        <td id="">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="">stuff</td>
        <td id="">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="">stuff</td>
        <td id="">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>

</div>

<!------------------------------->
    
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function getWeather() {
    var zipCode = document.getElementById('zipCodeEnter').value;
    var country = document.getElementById('countrySelect').value;
    if(zipCode=="" || country=="") {
        alert("Please complete form");
    }
    else{
        continue;
    }
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("windSpeed").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("windGust").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "stuff";
    document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "stuff";
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what is currently happening? Are there any errors in the console?

I think one possibility is that when you click the submit input, the form tries to post the data, effectively "refreshing" the page.

Comment: there should be an alert at the top of the screen if you don't fill in the zip code box, i was kind of just using that to test if the value was being passed to the function but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this circumstance, there's no need to use the  label, if you use the  label, in the getWeather function, you must use this.preventDefault() method to prevent the page jumped to "another" page by form post action. you can replace form with div label.Then, the meaning of id, id is short for identifier, if one page or frame has many elements with the same id value, only the first was selected.

Comment: so i would put this in for the action attribute? also how would i style the label if it isnt in a label tag?

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way would be to simply put the `required` attribute in your HTML inputs, this way you don't need javascript to validate it as the form won't let the user submit unless the input has some value.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="zipCode" placeholder="Required" id="zipCodeEnter" required>
```

Reference and working demo:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: i should have said that i still need the values passed because im going to be using them in a post request to a web server to get weather data and then display it on the webpage